# Обновление контента у всех пользователей, сидящих на странице

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

Предположим, что на сайте есть главная страницу (/), в которой находятся новости, выводящиеся из базы данных. После публикации новой новости нужно сделать так, чтобы у всех людей, которые находятся на странице / новость появилась сразу, без обновления страницы.
С помощью чего возможная подобная реализация?

*В качестве вывода новостей на сайт использую Flask*

Comment: Вы ж уже написали ответ в третьей метке вопроса

Comment: Можно с неким таймаутом опрашивать сервер на предмет новостей... И если получено что-то новое - изменять содержимое страницы.

Comment: Поднимите сокет и отслеживайте, кто где сидит. При изменении данных, отправляйте клиентам сообщение и пусть перерисовывают данные